# Parse a specific XML file with PHP and read it

Tags: php, xml, parsing, object

I want understand the way to read and parse this "XML" file. My code is working with another XML files and can't understand where I am wrong.

```
<F24 ZId="0" ZdId="0" PlikXml="0" rP="0" DCal="20130314">
  <Kraje i="35">...</Kraje>
  <Mecze>
    <M MId="1049553" LId="28541" _LId="28537" OId="230" SId="5" KId="220" LNr="2" C0="1363226400" ML="1" HId="2590" GId="2975" W="" HN="Pérez Zeledón" GN="Puntarenas FC" HRC="" HRCi="0" GRC="" GRCi="0" Info="" S1="0-0" S2="0-0" MStan="1" OTv="" L="0" A="0" Ao="4"/>
  </Mecze>
</F24>
```

That is the structure of XML file. I want to get `F24->Mecze->M{'GN'};` or something from "Mecze->M".

Code at the moment.

```
<?php

$file = '...';
$rss = simplexml_load_file($file);

foreach ($rss->{'M'} as $OO) { 

        $ht = $OO->{'HN'};

        echo $ht;

}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rss = simplexml_load_string('<F24 ZId="0" ZdId="0" PlikXml="0" rP="0" DCal="20130314">
  <Kraje i="35">...</Kraje>
  <Mecze>
    <M MId="1049553" LId="28541" _LId="28537" OId="230" SId="5" KId="220" LNr="2" C0="1363226400" ML="1" HId="2590" GId="2975" W="" HN="Pérez Zeledón" GN="Puntarenas FC" HRC="" HRCi="0" GRC="" GRCi="0" Info="" S1="0-0" S2="0-0" MStan="1" OTv="" L="0" A="0" Ao="4"/>
  </Mecze>
</F24>');
foreach ($rss->Mecze->M as $OO) { 

        echo $OO['HN'];

}
```

http://codepad.org/loNVfOew

Answer (score 0):

According to the structure of the demo data you'd need something like

foreach ($rss->Mecze->M as $OO)

or maybe

```
foreach ($rss->xpath('Mecze/M') as $OO)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try sax php http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-set-object.php and extract any node, attributes, or create any structure